# google maps in fragment crash

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to show a marker on my google map in my fragment. I can load the google map without problems but when i run mapFragment.getMapAsync(this), the app crashes and I don't know why. Any tips?

this is the code:

```
public class ISSLocation extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {    

    View v    
    GoogleMap mapAPI;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_iss, container, false);

        FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapAPI);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return v;
    }

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mapAPI = googleMap;

        LatLng location = new LatLng(19.389137, 76.031094);
        mapAPI.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Location"));
        mapAPI.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));         
    }
}
```

this is the layout xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapAPI"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">

    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

stacktrace:
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0fYY.png)

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: I added the stacktrace, however i don't think the error has anything to do with this problem because i have had that error for a long time and the app never crashed before with this error.

Comment: I know but this is what is shown when i start the app and when it crashes nothing changes to the stacktrace. The photo is from what the stacktrace shows when the app crashes.

Comment: I just noticed the problem.  When you have a SupportMapFragment nested inside a fragment, you need to use the fragment's child fragment manager.

Comment: you are right, thank you for helping me! @DanielNugent